# Double Stroke Dollar Sign in HTML (cifrão)

Tags: html, email, character-encoding

Is there a way to make a double stroke dollar sign with HTML -- also known as the cifrão in Portugese? Or does anybody have a good workaround for coding these into email designs -- besides using images?

I am coding *emails* for a creative team that uses this style, but we cannot use the font they design with and use on the site due to licensing issues... and pasting images every time a dollar sign comes up in commercial emailing is not really reasonable.

It's not critical, but really bothering my ego/OCD that I cannot make this work in 2015...

Comment: It's difficult to make it with pure HTML code. Consider using CSS also.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
&#x24;
```

but its a longer single line, not a double line dollar sign

Comment: I'm definitely up-voting this because it's interesting and I appreciate it -- but it appears that the answer is "it's not possible " :(